# Suma, Promedio Tiempos y Duraciones Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Actualmente tengo una base de datos en Power BI que contiene la información de tiempo y duraciones de actividades, necesito poder calcular promedios y/o suma de los tiempos y de las duraciones pero solo aparece la opcion de recuento y he intentado con añadiendo columnas calculadas con la informacion de la base pero igual no me da una opcion para sumar o de promedios cuando estoy armando un reporte, la idea es poder presentar un resumen con los promedios de los tiempos de duracion

[image: Base Datos]

[image: Opciones]

[image: Resumen]

Comment: Para que quieres sacar ese valor en el origen de datos , hazlo en el reporte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Power Query copia la columna, creando una idéntica, pero con el tipo de dato de fecha/hora. La llamaremos "Alert duration 2". Luego en Power BI compones una medida:

```
Duracion = 
VAR Segundos= SUMX('Tabla', HOUR('Tabla'[Alert duration 2]) * 3600+ MINUTE('Tabla'[Alert duration 2]) * 60 + SECOND('Tabla'[Alert duration 2]))
VAR Dias = TRUNC(Segundos/3600/24)
VAR Horas = TRUNC((Segundos-Days*3600*24)/3600)
VAR Minutos = TRUNC(MOD(Segundos,3600)/60)
VAR Segs = MOD(Segundos,60)
return 
IF((Horas + (Dias*24)) < 10, "0" & (Horas + (Dias*24)), (Horas + (Dias*24))) & ":" & IF(Minutos<10, "0" & Minutos, Minutos) & ":" & IF(Segs<10, "0" & Segs, Segs)
```